# Difficulties with p/invoke and EnumDisplaySettingsEx

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, user32

I am attempting to retrieve information on all the various monitors (and their adapters) present on a system. So far, my attempts at using `EnumDisplayDevices` to list all the monitors has worked great - it found two, the first being `"\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0"` (the second is just 2 and 1, respectively, but it's irrelevant to this question). Anyway, I then attempted to call `EnumDisplaySettingsEx` on it, passing the name of the monitor as above, but it always fails. Calls with a null name parameter succeed, but the `DEVMODE` structure returned says the `dmDeviceName` is "cdd" which I highly doubt is accurate. What am I doing wrong?

Oh, and I've tried using `EnumDisplaySettings` (the non-Ex one) and that doesn't even work with the null name parameter.

P/Invoke signatures (Ex's slightly modified from the one on pinvoke.net in a flailing attempt to get it to work):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettingsEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, EdsDwFlags dwFlags);
```

`DEVMODE` is defined at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DEVMODE.html. `EdsDwFlags` for now is always zero. `iModeNum` is -1 (for current settings).

And for some reason StackOveflow won't let me attach a C# tag to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot, you're supposed to pass a **display adapter** to this function, not a **monitor**. Passing just `"\\.\DISPLAY1"` worked fine.

I'm still getting garbage back for the `dmDeviceName` field, though, so I'd appreciate any suggestions as to how I got that wrong.

Comment: I suspect the "cdd" stands for "Canonical Display Driver" (there's a system file in Windows called cdd.dll that is the canonical display driver). If anyone knows otherwise, please correct me.

Comment: BTW, according to the docs for `DEVMODE.dmDeviceName` it's supposed to represent the same thing as `DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName`. You can call `EnumDisplayDevices`, passing in `"\\.\DISPLAY1"` and get the friendly/display name.