# EnumDisplaySettings not working with non-null device name parameter

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have the following code in a C++ Windows Desktop Application.

```
void GetDisplayMonitorInfo()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dispAdapter, dispDevice;
    DEVMODE dispDeviceSettings;
    wchar_t dispAdapterName[33], dispDeviceName[33];//32 + 1 null
    int iAdapter = 0, iDisplay = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&dispAdapter, sizeof(dispAdapter));
    ZeroMemory(&dispDevice, sizeof(dispDevice));
    ZeroMemory(&dispDeviceSettings, sizeof(dispDeviceSettings));

    dispAdapter.cb = sizeof(dispAdapter);
    dispDevice.cb = sizeof(dispDevice);
    dispDeviceSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dispDeviceSettings);

    //Foreach adapter
    //We pass NULL to get adapter infos
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, iAdapter, &dispAdapter, 0))
    {
        //Keep the name
        wcsncpy_s(dispAdapterName, dispAdapter.DeviceName, 33);
        //Remove warning C6054
        dispAdapterName[32] = L'\0';

        //foreach display connected to adapter
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(dispAdapterName, iDisplay, &dispDevice, 0))
        {
            //Keep the name
            wcsncpy_s(dispDeviceName, dispDevice.DeviceName, 33);
            //Remove warning C6054
            dispDeviceName[32] = L'\0';

            //Show informations
            if (EnumDisplaySettings(dispDevice.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dispDeviceSettings))
            {
                int j = 0; //DOESN'T WORK
            }
            //Show informations
            if (EnumDisplaySettings(dispDeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dispDeviceSettings))
            {
                int j = 0; //DOESN'T WORK
            }
            //Show informations
            if (EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dispDeviceSettings))
            {
                int j = 0; //WORKS
            }


            iDisplay++;
        }

        iAdapter++;
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function in the basic about box message loop created by visual studio.

```
// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;

    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        GetDisplayMonitorInfo(); //HERE
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I would like to know why the `EnumDisplaySettings` function returns false when I give a specific device name, but true when I pass NULL.

I read the [EnumDisplaySettings manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsa) and the [EnumDisplayDevices manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa) but I don't see why this code won't work.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm working on a remotely accessed windows 10 virtual machine running on VMware workstation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are copying `dispAdapter.DeviceName` and `dispDevice.DeviceName` to local `wchar_t[]` buffers, instead of just using them as-is?

Comment: Because I want to print it in a debug console

Comment: Why does that require making copies of them, though? You could use them as-is in the debug prints, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I could do that, but that won't solve the issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the end, I want to be able to tell if a cursor or a window position is in an available display. I want to keep in an array the list of monitors with names, positions and coverage they have. I want to be able to tell if a point is out of the screens I'm keeping.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your actual purpose? I tested, call `EnumDisplaySettings` with `dispAdapter.DeviceName` works fine.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, and there is also [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383970/difficulties-with-p-invoke-and-enumdisplaysettingsex) that has similar problems. If you set `lpszDeviceName` to the name of the display adapter, it will work, but if you set it to the monitor name, the function will fail. There is nothing in the documentation It is clearly stated that it needs to be set to the adapter name, so I will confirm it with Internal engineer, and response here if there is any update.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Sprite Look closer to the code I gave. The problem isn't with the `dispAdapter` variable but with the `dispDevice` variable. My bad if the code isn't clear enough.

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT Thanks for the feedback/help! I though a display adapter was meant to represent a gpu or something you can plug multiple displays in. I didn't think there could be only one display per adapter. Ex: If I run 2 gpus in SLI with 2 monitors connected in each one (4 total), I thought I would need to run 2 times in my first loop and 2 times in the secondary loop (one time per monitor detected). Anyways, I hope this makes my question clearer.